# Как добавить больше цветов?

Tags: python, tkinter

Как добавить больше цветов?

То есть сейчас у меня только два цвета и с каждым кликом цвет меняется на другой. А как добавить ещё и третий?

```
from tkinter import *
 
 
def bg1():
    root.configure(background="blue".format(clicks))
 
def bg2():
    root.configure(background="red".format(clicks))
 
def Clicker():
    global clicks
    global flag
    clicks += 1
    root.title("Clicks {}".format(clicks))
    if flag: bg1(); flag = False
    else: bg2(); flag = True
 
 
clicks = 0
flag = False
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
root.configure()
but = Button(width=30, command=Clicker)
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

На [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/tu1Dg8d2)

Comment: 1) Заведите список цветов 2) Кликом меняйте текущий индекс цвета: на следующий зацикленно или случайный 3) Обращайтесь к цвету по текущему индексу цвета

Answer (score 1):

(Вся работающая программа в конце этого ответа.)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Посмотрите на эту часть вашей программы

```
if flag: bg1(); flag = False
else: bg2(); flag = True
```

которую я напишу более красиво:

```
if flag: 
    bg1()
    flag = False
else: 
    bg2()
    flag = True
```

Видно, что переменна `flag`, которая определяет цвет, может иметь 2 состояния - `True` или `False`.

---

Значит, вам нужна переменная с более значениями, например `color` типа `int`.

В начало программы добавите возможности, например

```
BLUE  = 1
RED   = 2
GREEN = 3
```

и, естественно,

```
def bg3():
    root.configure(background="green")
```

Теперь вместо переменной `flag` используем `color`, т.е. вместо

```
clicks = 0
flag = False
```

(в нижней части вашей программы) напишите

```
clicks = 0
color  = BLUE          # Первоначальный цвет
```

вместо

```
global flag
```

в функции `Clicker()` напишите

```
global color
```

и управляющую часть (с которой я начинал) измените на

```
if color == BLUE: 
    bg1()
    color = RED             # BLUE -> RED

elif color == RED: 
   bg2()
   color = GREEN            # RED -> GREEN

elif color == GREEN:
   bg3()
   color = BLUE             # GREEN -> BLUE

else:
   pass   # Невозможно
```

---

Вся работающая программа:

```
from tkinter import *

BLUE = 1
RED = 2
GREEN = 3


def bg1():
    root.configure(background="blue")


def bg2():
    root.configure(background="red")


def bg3():
    root.configure(background="green")


def Clicker():
    global clicks
    global color
    clicks += 1
    root.title("Clicks {}".format(clicks))

    if color == BLUE:
        bg1()
        color = RED         # BLUE -> RED

    elif color == RED:
        bg2()
        color = GREEN       # RED -> GREEN

    elif color == GREEN:
        bg3()
        color = BLUE        # GREEN -> BLUE

    else:
        pass


clicks = 0
color = BLUE
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200")
root.configure()
but = Button(width=30, command=Clicker)
but.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: В `bg3` `format` лишний

Comment: @insolor, вы вполне прав (тоже в `bg1()` и в `bg2()` это лишние) - я только не хотел перепутать человека многими изменениями в его программе.

Comment: @insolor, я решил всё-таки изменить мой ответ для вашего комментария, т.к. это очень некрасиво. Спасибо.